# Can we ask what software is best for the job

Tags: discussion

I understand that asking questions about the choice of consumer electronics are not allowed, and with good reason. Similarly, opinion based questions otherwise too are not allowed. **I would like to know whether** **questions asking about the best simulation software and/or practice**, **related to the design of electronics** (such as a C-E amplifier), **or electrical devices** (such as a dc-dc converter- electric motor setup) **allowed**?

I am in conflict as to whether to ask them as they involve some opinion-related answers (as some them are commercial products), while on the other hand knowing and using simulation tools is a valuable skill for electrical engineers/hobbyists/students etc., and therefore knowing what the best tool is for the purpose beforehand goes a long way.

I have seen this question [What is the correct SE channel to ask about an electrical engineering SOFTWARE question?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5968/115280); however that question was related to the usage of a certain software, which usually does not bring opinionated answers; while I ask about questions regarding the choice of software tools, which has the possibility of strongly opinionated answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A opinion-based question might work in [our EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  The customs are more relaxed there.

"*What software is best?*" is such a common type of question that there is a separate stack for it: [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  It was established for all kinds of software, rather than electrical engineering specifically.

**Combined approach:** post a question to Software Recommendations SE, then go to our EE.SE chat - or other SE chats where right kinds of expertise might hang out  and post a link to the question there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing definitely sounds opinion-based, and therefore is not a good fit for this site.  *What software is best* is pretty much always a bad question because so much of "best" depends on personal choices.  And to make things worse, people often cling to their personal choices in a religious fashion.  So not only do such questions end up being about opinions, they sometimes start holy wars.

Don't do it.